# Understanding _ids array in CakePHP model data

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

Using CakePHP v3.1 w/ Postgres DB. When I retrieve records with associations I often see an extra array of `_ids`. Something like this:

```
    ...
    (int) 26 => [
        'agency_id' => (int) 23,
        'routes' => [
            '_ids' => (int) 2
        ]
    ]
```

Or sometimes:

```
     '_ids' => Array (
        0 => 1
        1 => 5
        2 => 3
        3 => 4
     )
]
```

I would like to understand:

1. How and why do these magic `_ids` appear?
2. Is there a way to control or prevent that behavior?

Comment: Are you really sure that you see them on DB data retrieval? And not maybe after creating/patching an entity with request data?

Comment: @ndm No I'm not really sure. I'm debugging variables in a unit test, so it's possible that they were just patched or something.

Comment: Actually I got a little confused myself now... after creating/patching an entity, these IDs should have been resolved to entites, so I'd guess that you simply look at request/form data.

Comment: @ndm I don't quite understand what you're recommending. Are you saying those fields were passed in from the request?

Comment: I don't know what your test looks like, there's not enough information to be able to tell where exactly it came from, or to suggest anything, but under normal circumstances the `_ids` key is either explicitly added into the (request) data, or half-way implicitly via the form helper. Search for `_ids` [**here**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html) and [**here**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html).

Comment: Show your code that generates the ids, the whole related code and the associations from the table(s) as well.

Comment: Those are the IDs of the associated records, in this case `routes`. Are they also returned as full entities, or are you just getting the IDs? I normally expect to get complete entities back when using `contain()`. The structure you are showing can be seen in the [CakePHP ORM documentation](https://github.com/cakephp/orm#saving-data) and the [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-belongstomany-data) under the "saving" sections. It would help to know how you build and execute the query and whether you are Lazy Loading associations.

Comment: @Ethan That sounds like an answer to me... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How and why do these magic _ids appear?

The `_ids` property generally comes *in from request* data. It could be left behind on an entity if the association isn't completely marshalled though.

If you an provide a way to reproduce `_ids` coming *out* of the ORM, please open an issue on github as that shouldn't be happening.